# How do I call a class into another class?

Tags: java, arrays, list

I do not get how to put the Card class into the Deck. Would you please explain how I can fix this?

Here are the instructions:

> You need to rewrite the constructor so that all 52 cards of a normal card deck are assigned to the cards array. Keep in mind that card information needs to be stored inside the Deck class and is not passed by parameter. Additionally, you need to re-define the toString method for the Deck class so that it can be used to display the attribute values in a convenient manner.  Make sure to take advantage of the toString method that already exists in the Card class.
>
> (You also need to add a shuffle method, which is called from the constructor.  The shuffle method is a private helper method in the Deck class. For this version you need to shuffle the deck by swapping the cards. Generate two random numbers in the [0..51] number range that will represent the indexes of the cards array and swap the cards. Make 1000 swaps and then display the cards. Use Math.random to generate random numbers.) <-This is a part of the instructions, but I don't think it matters in this situation because I what I want to know is how to do put the Card class in to the Deck.(but i still put it in *just in case*)

```
public class Lab11bvst
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{ 
  Deck deck = new Deck();
  System.out.println(deck);
}
}
    
class Deck 
{
private Card[] cards;
private int size;
   private String[ ] suits = {"Clubs","Diamonds","Hearts","Spades"};

public Deck() 
{
  size = 52;
  cards = new Card[size];
  
  
   }

 private shuffle(){
  
 }
}
```

the Card class:

```
public class Card
{
   private String suit;
   private String rank;
   private int value;

   public Card(String s, String r, int v)
   {
      suit = s;
      rank = r;
      value = v;
   }

   public String getSuit()       { return suit; }
   public String getRank()       { return rank; }
   public int getValue()         { return value; }

   public void setSuit(String s) { suit = s; }
   public void setRank(String r) { rank = r; }
   public void setValue(int v)   { value = v; } 

   public String toString()
   {
      return "[" + suit + ", " + rank + ", " + value + "]";
   }

   public boolean matches(Card otherCard) 
   {
return otherCard.getSuit().equals(this.suit)
&& otherCard.getRank().equals(this.rank)
&& otherCard.getValue() == this.value;
}
}
```

Comment: "this is very urgent-i need to turn this in by tomorrow.." - That's really not our fault.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Please note that JavaScript and Java are worlds apart, and one should not tag a question with both unless one is actually using both. I'll remove the JS tag.

Comment: I deliberately quote-formatted the code since it is part of the homework - the classes are supplied by the instructor.

Comment: sorry.. I did not realize that by saying it is urgent i would bother you. I apologize.
@halfer thank you for telling me

Comment: OK. I would suggest you make a start on this homework, and ask a more focussed question if you get stuck. I would start off by using two nested loops (one for suit and one for value) and then using the combined suit/value codes to instantiate a card and push it into the deck array.

Answer (score 0):

"rewrite the constructor so that all 52 cards of a normal card deck are assigned to the cards array"

Right now, the constructor is setting the size of the deck to 52 cards, and then it initializes an array to hold 52 elements. You'll need to populate the cards array by creating cards for all 52 cards normally found in a deck. The constructor of your Card class helps you do this.

For example, you could start by adding an Ace of Diamonds and adding it to the cards array:

```
Card aceD = new Card("Diamonds", "Ace", 1);
cards[0] = aceD;
```

and then add all 52 cards to your cards array.

Comment: I'm not sure if this answers your question of "how to put the Card class into the Deck" but I hope it helps! --also, the way halfer mentioned above is much more efficient, but I just wanted to make sure you knew how to use a class in another class